# How to make this menu occupy all the remaining space's width?

Tags: css, html

There is a menu :

```
<div id="divmenuppal"> // this the menu
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Administration</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Indoor</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Garden</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
                     <li><hr></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
                     <li><hr></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Structure</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">All-in-One Team Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Air &amp; Electrical Reels</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Field Drags</a></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Field Marking Equipment</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Batter's Box Templates</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dryline Markers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Field Paint</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Garden</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Field Sprayers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Stencils</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Field Tarps</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Area Tarps</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Growth Covers / Protectors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Infield Tarps</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tarp Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">Hand Tools</a></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Irrigation, Hoses, Nozzles</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Hoses &amp; Hose Reels</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Irrigation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Nozzles</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">Layout Tools</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Moisture Removal</a></li>
                     <li><hr></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Mound Fortification</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Mowers &amp; Stripers</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Soil Management</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Soil Amendments</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Spreaders &amp; Sweepers</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Exercice</a>
                <ul>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Baseball - Softball</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Base Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bases &amp; Home Plates</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Game Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pitching Rubbers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Batting Practice Equipment</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Backstops</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Infield Screens</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Jugs Pitching Machines</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Turf Mats</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Turf Protectors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Replacement Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Indoor</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Portable Mounds</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Batting Practice Mounds</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Game Mounds</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Practice Mounds</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Football</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">First Down Markers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Football Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Football Goalposts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Soccer</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Soccer Goals</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Soccer Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Contribuables et biens</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Ladders &amp; Sticks</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Hurdles</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Training Accessories</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Smart-Cart Training System</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Smart-Hurdle Collection</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Recettes</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Field Design</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Edition</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Field Design</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Outils</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Field Design</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="breadcrumbs" style="clear:left;"> // this is the breadcrumbs
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="bread">
      <li><a href="http://localhost/impots/index.php?action=Accueil" target="_self">Accueil</a></li><li><a href="http://localhost/impots/contribuable.php?action=ContriGererContribuable" target="_self">Gestion des contribuables</a></li><li><a>Fiche d'un contribuable</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="bread pull-right">
      <li style="color: #000;padding: 5px;font-size: 11px;font-weight: bold;">Fiche d'un contribuable</li>
    </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The css of the menu :

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 100;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul.dropdown ul {
    width: 220px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #40617C;
}

ul.dropdown li:not(.menuppal):not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
{
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

hr {
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    border-top: 0;
}

/*
 LEVEL ONE : MAIN MENU
 */
ul.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown li.menuppal {
    float: left;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #000 url(../images/menuLight.png) repeat-x top left;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #222;
}

ul.dropdown li.menuppal a {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: #000000;
}

/* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.menuppal:hover {
    background: #ccc url('../images/menuDark.png') repeat-x 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
}
/*
        FIN LEVEL ONE
 */

/*
 LEVEL TWO
 */
ul.dropdown ul {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}

/* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown li.menuppal ul li a {
    border-right: none;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.dropdown  li.menuppal ul li a:hover {
    background: #07243a;
}

ul.dropdown  li.menuppal ul li a:visited {
    word-break: break-all;
}

/*
 LEVEL THREE
 */
ul.dropdown ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top:0!important;
}

/*
LEVEL FOUR
 */
ul.dropdown ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top:0!important;
}

ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

At runtime the menu is not occupying all the horizontal space :

[image]

So how to make the menu fill the remaining space like in this image :

[image]

Comment: Replace `ul.dropdown ul` from `220px` to `100%` and set the background image like the `ul.dropdown li.menuppal`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul.dropdown {
    background: #000 url(../images/menuLight.png) repeat-x top left;
}`

Comment: the background is dark , how to make it have same image background as the ul ?

Comment: remove background  li.menuppal

Answer (score 0):

Use flex layout. I add following code to the bottom of your CSS and it did the trick:

```
#divmenuppal > .dropdown {
    display: flex;
}
.dropdown .menuppal:last-child {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w2n79nsy/

Comment: but this will stretch all LI's

Comment: @Era Not all. That's why there's `>`. Did you see my fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

ok I found it from @SunilDalal's answer :

```
ul.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000 url('menuLight.png') repeat-x top left;
}
```